# The user needs to pick an option from a 100 items list. What is the best way to make this happen in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a bot where the user needs to choose a specific item from a big list, over 100 items. How can I do this in Dialogflow ? I used a Webview for this on FB Messenger but in Dialogflow this is not an option.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: What surface are they using to interact with your app?  If it is a screen-only experience like a phone and they are typing and looking at a screen you will have more options.  If you are including voice-only users your options will be limited.  Please update your question to clarify what surface your users are using for this interaction

Comment: Hi Mark,
I am asking the user his occupation(I have an available occupations list). The user can add his answer by typing, using their phone.

Comment: If the user *must* use their phone screen make sure to require a screen (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities), as for the selection you can help your user and the system understand expected values with developer entities: https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities just sub coffee drink type for occupation, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the surface capabililties link Mark. I am using entities ... but they are not really helpful.. a user can title his occupation as he wants, or misspell it, she will just receive a message telling him his answer is not correct. I guess there is no simple way to help the user choose an item from a long list of predefined items. :(

Comment: When no match you can tell the user that there is choice is not valid and use a matching algorithm to make a targeted suggestion (using your own fulfillment).  You should account for synonyms like "software developer" and "software engineer" in your solution.  The last sentence of your latest comment is a great encapsulation of your question, you should update your question to more clearly reflect what you are trying to do and offer what you have already tried if you want this to keep moving forward.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a bit harsh, but my first thought is that you need to rethink your design. I can think of very few cases where I would be presented with a list of 100 items, need to pick a specific one from them, and would find that a pleasant experience.

Imagine walking into a restaurant and the waiter, instead of handing you a menu, started reciting every item that is available. Even menus are broken into sections for a reason.

If the users have an idea what they need to choose, give them the option to type that in at any point, of course. (For example, if they need to pick a country from a list.)

But otherwise, help them narrow down their choices to only what applies, in the same way a waiter might help you narrow down choices by asking if you wanted fish, beef, or something else.